# Production Config between Intranet REST server and React Apps

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Folks, forgive me if this is a repeat question: I couldn't think of how to phrase it in the search engine.  I'm developing an Intranet-based set of applications with the front end (individual apps) in React and the back-end using node.js and Express.  I had been using Electron JS but like the Express solution since all web browsers on the Intranet can use the apps.

I'm running into a bit of a circular dependency when it comes to production, though.  Since my REST back-end handles all local calls (like node fs) I use REST calls to load and save preferences files from the front end.  However, I'd like to be able to set the REST URI from a config file or setting.  Since the only way I can access this setting is a call to the REST back-end, I'm stuck.  It's possible the client may want to change the host URL and the port for the server.  This will affect all axios calls to the REST back end in every React application I have.  Instead of calling http://localhost:5000/api-call/ I'd like the localhost and port number to be read from config.

I am transpiling the React apps and storing them in a static folder underneath the REST server.  I would like to avoid something complex or additional like REDIS or another local database.  My projects don't require any heavy database setups.

Am I simply implementing poor architecture here?  I even thought of env variables but then will get into setting them on each client's system which takes away from the flexibility of using a web server in the first place.  Any thoughts to move me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I knew if I posted this, I might find an answer.

I'm not sure how elegant a solution this is but I could test the env for development vs. production.  If in production, I can then use window.href (host and port) to get the information I need.  I think this will work but would still love to hear some other thoughts from those with far more experience than I have!